# grub2 error: out of disk

Tags: linux, boot, external-hard-drive, grub

I'm trying to make a 250G USB hard disk Ubuntu-bootable on a Compaq nc6220 laptop.

I've removed all other disks, so /dev/sda (the USB disk) is the only disk other than CDROM.

I installed Ubuntu 9.10 to this disk from the live CD, putting the bootloader on /dev/sda . The default system couldn't be booted, and nothing I did in the Grub menu/cmdline helped.

So I chrooted onto the disk and did `grub-install /dev/sda`. That seemed to work fine, but Grub (1.97 beta 4) keeps coming up with

> error: out of disk

Even when I drop to the command line to do something simple like `ls` or `help`, it's always the same error message.

Any hints for resolving this, please?

Comment: Wait a minute, are you trying to make an _external_ USB-Harddisk bootable?

Comment: @Bobby: Yes, I was trying to make an extern USB disk bootable. It's possible to configure it as bootable in the BIOS, and it does kinda boot, though inconsistently.

I gave up without figuring out the whole problem, but it seems to have been timing related. It would work sometimes and sometimes not. I'm hoping that by the next time I have similar problems, grub2 will be more standard and have more robust error handling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does Grub2 drop you into a *grub rescue>* prompt after this error?  [This thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1331730) suggests that getting the rescue prompt means Grub2 can't find a usable *grub.cfg* file.  See [Grub2 Rescue Mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Rescue%20Mode) for a method to locate your system installation and boot it.  In short, you need these commands (see the link for details):

1. `ls` (displays the partitions and devices Grub can see)
2. `set prefix=(hdX,Y)/boot/grub` [*]
3. `set root=(hdX,Y)`[*]
4. `set` (shows Grub's environment; inspect the *prefix=* listing; make sure it matches what you set in step 3)
5. `ls /boot/` (should show the contents of your system's */boot* -- kernels, initrd images, the grub folder, etc)
6. `insmod (hdX,Y)/boot/grub/linux.mod`
7. `linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sdXY ro` [**]
8. `initrd /initrd.img`
9. `boot`

   - [*] replace *(hdX,Y)* with a value shown in the output of step 1, such as *(hd0,1)* or *(hd3,9)*
   - [**] replace *sdXY* with the correct designation, such as *sda1* or *sdc9*.  *Y* is the same as in *(hdX,Y)* but *X* will be a letter instead of a number.

If you can boot following those directions, you may be able to fix grub just by running:

```
sudo grub-install
sudo update-grub2
```

---

An alternative is suggested in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/477430).  According to that, the error is generated by this line in Grub's configuration (*grub.cfg*):

```
if [ -n ${have_grubenv} ]; then save_env recordfail; fi
```

Removing that line seems to have helped fix booting problems, but some report the error still persists.  See [this post](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/477430/comments/6) for how to remove that line from the Grub menu during boot, and for how to remove it from the configuration file generation script (*/etc/grub.d/10_linux*).

Unfortunately neither of these resources indicate what's causing the error.

Comment: Sorry to be so late with my answer: No, Grub didn't drop me into a rescue prompt; it came out with an error message and halted.

I've meanwhile given up, partly because the requirement I had went away. Hopefully things will work better next time I try this stunt, whenever that will be. I'm going to accept your answer in appreciation of the work you put in, thank you!

Comment: When I get to step 5. @ls /boot/@ I get the error "out of disk" again. Any idea what I should do at this point?