# Ubuntu grub fails to start, error: out of disk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub

My computer has become quite strange the last days, 
last week grub stopped working and just halted at the grub prompt.

I can manually start the system by writing

```
insmod /boot/grub/linux.mod
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1 ro
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

But if I type something like

```
cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

I get a error:

```
error: out of disk
```

Does anybody know why this occurs?

Thanks 
Johan

---

**Note**:

I don't think that /boot/ is full, since it is part of / (5% used).

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             285G   14G  258G   5% /
none                  1.5G  312K  1.5G   1% /dev
none                  1.5G  184K  1.5G   1% /dev/shm
none                  1.5G  348K  1.5G   1% /var/run
none                  1.5G  4.0K  1.5G   1% /var/lock
none                  1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /lib/init/rw
```

**Note**:

The system is a Ubuntu 10.04 based system on a old HP laptop.

---

**Related questions**:

- [grub2 error: out of disk](https://superuser.com/questions/89307/grub2-error-out-of-disk)