# straight to grub prompt on boot

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, grub

I am very lost. I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 10.04 on a laptop. First reboot was fine. I ran all the recommended upgrades, and now every time I start I get just a

```
grub>_
```

prompt. No error message, just the prompt, and a little banner at the top saying grub's version and telling me that I have minimal bash style editing. I've tried:

1) Re-installing grub via

```
sudo grub-install sda
```

(There is only one disk with only two partitions, one primary, and one for swap)

2) Changed

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_TIMEOUT=30
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="rootdelay=90"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rootdelay=90"
```

in /etc/default/grub. No luck. I *can* boot with the following:

```
grub> set root=(hd0,1)
grub> probe (hd0,1) -u
c00fadde-f7e8-45e7-a4da-0235605f756
grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-21-generic root=UUID=c00fadde-f7e8-45e7-a4da-0235605f756 rootdelay=90
grub> initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-21-generic
grub> boot
```

And then everything seems to be fine from there. From the grub prompt if I try

```
configfile /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

The screen clears and I get another grub> prompt.

So, seriously, what could the problem be?

edit:

### Full text of /boot/grub/grub.cfg

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ ${prev_saved_entry} ]; then
  set saved_entry=${prev_saved_entry}
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z ${boot_once} ]; then
    saved_entry=${chosen}
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n ${have_grubenv} ]; then if [ -z ${boot_once} ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set c00fadde-f7e8-45e7-a4da-0235c605f756
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=640x480
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod vbe
  if terminal_output gfxterm ; then true ; else
    # For backward compatibility with versions of terminal.mod that don't
    # understand terminal_output
    terminal gfxterm
  fi
fi
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set c00fadde-f7e8-45e7-a4da-0235c605f756
set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
set lang=en
insmod gettext
if [ ${recordfail} = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=30
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.32-21-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set c00fadde-f7e8-45e7-a4da-0235c605f756
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-21-generic root=UUID=c00fadde-f7e8-45e7-a4da-0235c605f756 ro rootdelay=90  rootdelay=90
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-21-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 2.6.32-21-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set c00fadde-f7e8-45e7-a4da-0235c605f756
    echo    'Loading Linux 2.6.32-21-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-21-generic root=UUID=c00fadde-f7e8-45e7-a4da-0235c605f756 ro single rootdelay=90
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-21-generic
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set c00fadde-f7e8-45e7-a4da-0235c605f756
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,1)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set c00fadde-f7e8-45e7-a4da-0235c605f756
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
if [ ${timeout} != -1 ]; then
  if sleep --verbose --interruptible 10 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
```

### output of update-grub

```
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-21-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

### contents of /boot

```
total 14280
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  640617 2010-04-16 09:01 abi-2.6.32-21-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  115847 2010-04-16 09:01 config-2.6.32-21-generic
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 2010-09-08 02:42 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7968754 2010-09-02 01:49 initrd.img-2.6.32-21-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  160280 2010-03-23 05:37 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1687378 2010-04-16 09:01 System.map-2.6.32-21-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1196 2010-04-16 09:03 vmcoreinfo-2.6.32-21-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4029792 2010-04-16 09:01 vmlinuz-2.6.32-21-generic
```

Comment: Related? http://superuser.com/questions/173852/ubuntu-grub-fails-to-start-error-out-of-disk

Comment: I've tested your `grub.cfg` in a virtual machine that's a lot like your setup (single drive with only Ubuntu 10.04 i386, default partitioning). I only replaced the root filesystem UUID and the kernel version. It worked. So that's not the problem.

Comment: Well, I think I fixed it. I upped the GRUB_TIMEOUT even more so that it's not 90. I've rebooted twice and it booted as expected... so I guess that's all it was.

Answer (score 2):

So I have Ubuntu 9.04, perhaps that will be close enough to compare.

The lines in `/boot/grub/menu.lst` are

```
title           Ubuntu 9.04, kernel 2.6.28-16-server

uuid            a0ebaed5-072b-4591-9967-bcf4b5f9a507

kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.28-16-server root=UUID=a0ebaed5-072b-4591-9967-bcf4b5f9a507 ro quiet splash

initrd          /boot/initrd.img-2.6.28-16-server
```

Do you have lines in this file to point to the image? Do they point to the correct image?

Comment: That answer is about Grub1, but cheshirekow is trying to configure Grub2.

Comment: Yes, I do. The lines seem fine. I even tried manually editing /boot/grub/grub.cfg to get rid of all the scripty stuff and manually enter the stuff I know is correct, but that did not work either. I could have messed up the format though so maybe that's not the best information. Note I have since run update-grub so my changes were over written.

Comment: @Gilles, also yes... you're right, the commands are different in grub2

Answer (score 1):

Most plausible answer considering the initial data:

Your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is damaged. It is generated by the `update-grub` command, so first try running this command. Note that you must rerun `update-grub` every time you modify `/etc/default/grub`, as indicated by a comment at the top of the file. You must rerun `update-grub` every time you install, upgrade or remove a kernel as well, but the Ubuntu packages will take care of that for you.

If running `update-grub` doesn't solve the problem, edit your question to add: the contents of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`; the full output of `update-grub` on the terminal; the output of `ls -l /boot`.

**EDIT**: I tried the posted `grub.cfg` on a similar configuration, and it worked. So that's not the problem.

---

Very wild shot: could there be a nonprintable character in `grub.cfg` (copied from `/etc/default/grub` by the scripts)? The following command should output nothing:

```
<cheshirekow.grub.cfg tr '\t' ' ' | LC_ALL=C grep '[^ -~]' | cat -A
```

Comment: I tried that, several times. I will update my question

Comment: Well, thanks for trying the config. I guess it's good to know that's not the problem. I tried running that command, though I don't know exactly what it's doing (I know... dangerous) but in any case cheshirekow.grub.cfg was not found (obviously) I'm guessing that's what you used for your test so I tried /boot/grub/grub.cfg and it printed out the whole thing. Maybe it's a weird line ending thing then or something? The tr command replaces tabs with spaces right? And then we're grepping weird characters? what's the LC_ALL thing?

Comment: @cheshirekow: `grep` is told to look for a line containing a non-printable character. I goofed with `LC_ALL=C`: I meant to apply it to `grep` (because the character range ` -~` doesn't work in all locales). The extra `tr` call indeed translates tabs to spaces, I included it because specifying a tab on the grep command line is hard to do in a copy-pastable way. If the command did in fact print out every line, it could be a consequence of your locale. If the command with the `LC_ALL=C` applied to grep prints out every line, the problem is indeed non-grub-supported line endings in `grub.cfg`.