# Linux got really slow

Tags: linux, boot, memory

Recently my machine has become very slow and I don't know why? I've re-installed my Linux ( Ubuntu, Xubuntu ) several times. But everytime, after using a few times. It becomes slow again. I means really slow - webbrowsers are always lag, everything I do, i have to wait T.T

Here's it's brief spec:
Intel Core i5-2410M
4GB DDR3 RAM
Ati Radeon HD 6630

It's supposed to run linux flawlessly :(
And one more thing, most of the time, I receive this error while booting:
[image]

```
hieusun@ubuntu:/$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x32e36372

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1          96      768000   de  Dell Utility
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2   *          96        6470    51201251    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda3            6471       10294    30716280   83  Linux
/dev/sda4           10295       60801   405697447    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           10295       31966   174080308+  83  Linux
/dev/sda6           31967       32476     4096543+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7           32477       60801   227520531    7  HPFS/NTFS
hieusun@ubuntu:/$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3              29G  3.4G   25G  13% /
none                  1.6G  712K  1.6G   1% /dev
none                  1.6G  112K  1.6G   1% /dev/shm
none                  1.6G  132K  1.6G   1% /var/run
none                  1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /var/lock
/dev/sda5             164G  1.4G  154G   1% /home
```

vmstat:

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu---- 
r b     swpd free    buff  cache   si so     bi bo    in cs      us sy id wa 
0 2      0   2433924 58436 447752   0  0     100 39   114 255     3  1 85 11
```

Comment: *It's supposed to run linux flawlessly* Nothing runs linux flawlessly ;)

Comment: Have you checked disk space?

Comment: @Paul: On a freshly installed box?

Comment: @David.  Yes, an undersized partition is undersized no matter when linux was installed.

Comment: @Paul: And why did I get a downvote? When source is infected it's infected. Most likely with his box there isn't an undersized partition?

Comment: @Paul: The disk space is fine. 30GB for root directory, 100GB for home folder, 4GB for swap-area

The first time the error occured is when I started to use eclipse ( with eclim ) - I don't know if it caused the error.

Comment: @SimonSheehan :)) Ok, not flawlessly, but it should run not that sloww :(

Comment: @MinhHieu I think the grub error we are seeing there may be unrelated to the slowness.  Can you add an `fdisk -l` and `df -h` to the question?  Please add any additional information to the question so that the comments don't get out of hand.

Comment: @MinhHieu Is the slowness you experience primarily when doing network related things (web surfing) or does it also slow down when navigating the file system, and opening windows?  Can you post a `vmstat` during a slowdown?

Comment: `procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 0  2      0 2433924  58436 447752    0    0   100    39  114  255  3  1 85 11`

Comment: @Paul It lags very much when I'm using web browser and also lags when I'm navigating files and switching windows

Comment: Well nothing looks too bad in that vmstat - no swapping, a bit of io wait though that might be worth exploring. cpu is doing very little.  You might want to run vmstat for a while `vmstat 10` and see if any of the number spike in response to slowdowns.

Comment: here is the result: http://pastebin.com/jenjnDMb

Answer (score 1):

### Here is what is really wrong:

[`error: (hd0) out of disk`](https://superuser.com/questions/89307/grub2-error-out-of-disk), [`assert: error stack overflow detected`](http://www.radare.org/cgi-bin/hg/radare2/diff/3eb79588d012/libr/fs/p/grub/kern/err.c) are GRUB2 errors.

They basically mean that GRUB2 can't read or write to the disk, and by trying multiple attempts to try to access your disk it keeps generating errors such that finally the small error stack fills up and you get an error that it can't display any further messages because it got out of allocated memory.

### Here is what to do:

- Your first steps should be reinstalling GRUB2 or perhaps trying a different boot loader.

  Make sure that you get your GRUB configuration file (`menu.lst` or whatever) is correct...
- Your second check should be running checks against your hard disk to see if it is still fine.
- Dependent on the outcome of that, either reinstall your OS or get a new hard disk.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a virus. If you get a stack overflow message maybe Linux has found something is writing something to the stack and beyond. I would delete the disk and re-install again.

Comment: Its a freshly installed system, he claims - a virus is quite unlikely.

Comment: @SimonSheehan: That's what the message is saying. I've never seen this message and also there isn't a guarantee his source is infected.

Comment: @David if you have never seen this message, then your virus conclusion must surely be baseless?

Comment: @Paul: Not really because the message is saying something. It happens a stack overflow. A stack overflow can be cause of evil software. It's just logic. I don't need to know everything to put my foot one after another.

Comment: I've deleted all the partition and then do the partitioning again. How can it be infected ??

Comment: @MinhHieu It is very unlikely to be a virus, we need to look at more likely causes first.  Can you edit your question and include an `fdisk -l` and a `df -h`

Comment: @MinhHieu: Maybe the server is hacked and binaries are replaced? Or the programmer has do some fun thing and wrote a backdoor? Or your friend is backstab you? Did you try to read the S.M.A.R.T status of the disk and check if the disk is full?

Comment: @David No, I've said, it's a totally fresh install, the disk is full of free space :(

Comment: @David: Please get your facts straight. [Stack overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) have nothing to do with anything you just mentioned, and are not necessarily bad and could be just a programming mistake by the developer; what you are talking about are buffer overflows which is the type that is usually exploited.

Comment: @TomWijsman: What facts? Would you compile a message into Linux and warn about a buffer overflow? I think you understood me. Of course I mean buffer overflow.

Comment: @David: However, this is a Stack Overflow. Of course you would compile a message into Linux that warns you when a certain module/firmware/driver/application/service writes out of its memory boundaries, or does something that causes the kernel to do so. It's a very far-fetched conclusion to state that this is an exploit, which is about the rarest thing to happen in this situation...

Comment: @TomWijsman: I didn't wrote that article but it said itself: For other uses, see Stack overflow (disambiguation). And then When a program attempts to use more space than is available on the call stack (that is, when it attempts to access memory beyond the call stack's bounds, which is essentially a buffer overflow.

Comment: @David: That's just an assumption, I don't read any of that in the error. Furthermore, I don't see [any leads to a buffer overflow](http://www.radare.org/cgi-bin/hg/radare2/diff/3eb79588d012/libr/fs/p/grub/kern/err.c), it's just GRUB generating a ton of errors because of HDD problems...

Comment: @TomWijsman: Do you know Sherlock Holmes? Of course it's a rare thing but it's not so rare in other places on the internet to have backdoors, virus and such. And for me the message looks like something like that. I told him delete the disk again to fix it. That's all!?

Comment: Not sure if you are trolling or don't understand that errors within GRUB can not be the result of viruses...

Comment: @TomWijsman: I just like Linux excuse my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Download puppy linux or other distro with gparted that will run in RAM, burn ISO to cd, boot it.

Backup data (puppy uses pburn or you can mount an external drive) and fix your disk with Gparted or just start over with a clean partitioning.

Install your favorite OS.